# TortoiseGit asks me for a password when I try to Push

Tags: git, gitlab

I am using TortoiseGit (latest version) on Windows10. I installed Git as well. My company uses GitLab.

I downloaded the files from GitLab, set up a directory on my Xampp server and started to make change on the website.

Then setup the repository on my Xampp project folder and tried to use TortoiseGit.

I manage to commit changes but when I want to Push TortoiseGit asks me for  git@dev.cobweb.biz password although I use SSH key.

I haven't setup any password during the installation TortoiseGit and it never ask me to set up a password. I don't understand what password I am asking for when I hit Sync - Push.

I setup Putty keygen and added it's path in settings.
My URL is correct: http://dev.cobweb.biz:2380
Push URL is correct as well: ssh://git@dev.cobweb.biz:2323/upwork/drinkrosevibes.com.git

[image]

Please help me as I can't push the commits and actually I can't do my job.

[image]

Comment: I know nothing of TortoiseGit or Windows. But on Mac, you have to do a push in the Terminal first, so that the URL becomes trusted for SSH. After that, communication works automatically thru an IDE like Sourcetree.

Comment: Have you added your public key to your GitHub repository? Also, are you comfortable with command line?

Comment: @zedfoxus, I have not access to the remote Gitlab repository. I can add commands through command line but I don't know the commands and what command line to use - windows or Git

Comment: If you don't have access to the remote Gitlab repository, I don't think you can access it with TortoiseGit or anything else. You'll have to have read/write access to it. If you have access to it, you must have an account. Using that account you should be able to log on to GitLab and check whether SSH keys are added to your profile or to the repository.

Comment: Yes, thanks, I did it and added SSH key to the remote repository. Push doesn't require a password but gives me an error.

Answer (score 1):

It asks for a password, because TortoiseGit does not find your SSH key.
No key means: fallback to the *next* authentication method: the remote account password (the one for `git`, which you don't have and should never have)

Make sure you have:

- register your public key on Your GitLab reunning on dev.cobweb.biz
- put our putty key associated to your origin SSH URL, as [seen in this tutorial](https://help.cloudforge.com/hc/en-us/articles/215243143-Configure-TortoiseGIT-client-to-work-with-SSH-keys-on-Windows)

[image: https://p13.zdusercontent.com/attachment/205656/PkK2R6Z4dtQYzXaBUrcEeEVvK?token=eyJhbGciOiJkaXIiLCJlbmMiOiJBMTI4Q0JDLUhTMjU2In0..E6Bn4yhz4IVbXhTIJiPV4A.4ZsG9H_MCTg26SOJ07JIe49KVm6wfgWLnOy7EgbqDdvtURYBPopjAJ-reWuUp28sVb87WeNN39bjJuhsg4qWa-nPC4MKeo_RFjv_cfcBCLAzwxDyyRs33fE_YL1kDwmtjGcSJkE37PoafIObvszA42K9pDLtAUSm8IvNkgkYm4vfr2Z3cWORks23cnTlyGORJTvhCx8-rXnMyMEuFNPyjKWbnsbyt_XOaZYP5f3ab-Fe23iT2VpwuLb9zqgZpWtJ1gbXVtNDCOqrk71jle_7XA.xGLcUNqn0Yog-zxKWg9P6w]

For the pull URL, make sure to use the full HTTP URL:

```
http://dev.cobweb.biz:2380/upwork/drinkrosevibes.com.git
```

(not just `http://dev.cobweb.biz:2380/`, which is the URL if the server, not of the repository on that server)

Comment: Thank you. I added the SSH key and now it doesn't ask me for password but Push gives me an error

Comment: @Jenny Sure: the PULL URL is not correct: see my edited answer.